# raspberry u-boot load image and run image from sd card

Tags: raspberry-pi, u-boot

I have compiled and installed u-boot from https://github.com/gonzoua/u-boot-pi/tree/rpi on the Raspberry PI. Works great. It boots fine and works great (see http://arrizza.org/wiki/index.php/RPI_U-boot). I can load the example apps using the s-rec version of the executable.

Now I'd like to create an image, put it on the sd card (the same sd card the u-boot image is on) and then load and execute that image. That is the same as the s-rec process: load the image via s-rec and then use "go" to execute, but instead of loading across the serial port just get the image off the sd card.

I have tried using:

```
load mmc 0 0x0100000 hello_world.bin
```

and then

```
go 0x0100000
```

it loads ok:

```
U-Boot> fatload mmc 0 0x01000000 hello_world.bin
reading hello_world.bin
594 bytes read in 27222 ms (0 Bytes/s)
U-Boot> go 0x01000000
## Starting application at 0x01000000 ...
```

but the rPI self-reboots.

- I also tried fatload with the same results
- I tried creating an image using ./imagetool-uncompressed.py and then using load or fatload and go but no joy
- I tried load/fatload with bootm and still no go

Anything else available for me to try?

John

Update: @microMolvi pointed out I used the wrong address. I re-ran it:

```
U-Boot> load mmc 0 0x01001000 hello_world.bin 
reading hello_world.bin
594 bytes read in 27200 ms (0 Bytes/s)
U-Boot> go 0x01001000
## Starting application at 0x01001000 ...
<snip>about 100 garbage characters<snip>
<I pressed Enter here>
## Application terminated, rc = 0x0
U-Boot>
```

And here's the output of printenv:

```
U-Boot> printenv
arch=arm
baudrate=115200
board=rpi_b
board_name=rpi_b
bootargs=dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=656 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=416 bcm2708.boardrev=0xe bcm2708.serial=0x4e82105a smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:82:10:5A sdhci-bcm2708.emmc_clock_freq=100000000 vc_mem.mem_base=0x1ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x20000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
bootcmd=if mmc rescan ${mmcdev}; then if run loadbootenv; then run importbootenv; fi; if run loadbootscript; then run bootscript; fi; fi
bootenv=uEnv.txt
bootscript=echo Running bootscript from mmc${mmcdev} ...; source ${loadaddr}
cpu=arm1176
filesize=0x252
importbootenv=echo Importing environment from mmc ...; env import -t $loadaddr $filesize
loadaddr=0x00200000
loadbootenv=fatload mmc ${mmcdev} ${loadaddr} ${bootenv}
loadbootscript=fatload mmc ${mmcdev} ${loadaddr} boot.scr
mmcdev=0
soc=bcm2835
stderr=serial,lcd
stdin=serial
stdout=serial,lcd
usbethaddr=B8:27:EB:82:10:5A
vendor=raspberrypi

Environment size: 1092/16380 bytes
U-Boot>
```

Comment: Hi John,
0x0100000 is not equal to 0x01000000 :)
Can you please provide us the output of
`U-Boot>printenv`

Comment: See above for an update. I'm assuming from your response that it *should* work ok!?

Comment: By the way I also tried: `load mmc 0 $loadaddr hello_world.bin` and then `go $loadaddr` and finally I also tried loading hello_world.srec.  This just reset the rPI.

Comment: No I wasn't sure about the procedure, just caught the typo :D
I faced the same problem in past on an arm11mpcore board, and was unable to solve it.
I'll try the solution you posted below, hope it works for me as well :)

Answer (score 4):

Ok, it looks like you can't just load the bin files just anywhere.

Here's what I did:
1) I reloaded the s-rec version

```
U-Boot> loads
## Ready for S-Record download ...

## First Load Addr = 0x0C100000
## Last  Load Addr = 0x0C100251
## Total Size      = 0x00000252 = 594 Bytes
## Start Addr      = 0x0C100000
U-Boot>
```

Note the "Start Addr", it's 0x0C10-00000

2) I reset the rPI and then loaded the bin at 0x0C10-0000

```
U-Boot> load mmc 0 0x0C100000 hello_world.bin
reading hello_world.bin
594 bytes read in 15644 ms (0 Bytes/s)
```

3) and run it from the same addr:

```
U-Boot> go 0x0C100000
## Starting application at 0x0C100000 ...
Example expects ABI version 6
Actual U-Boot ABI version 6
Hello World
argc = 1
argv[0] = "0x0C100000"
argv[1] = "<NULL>"
Hit any key to exit ... 

## Application terminated, rc = 0x0
U-Boot>
```

I'm not sure where the default address 0x0C10-0000 comes from, so at this point I don't know how to change it during the compilation/link yet, but it is documented here:

```
u-boot-pi-rpi/doc/README.standalone
```

This says that ARM based boards like the rPI are loaded and started at 0x0C10-0000:
   The default load and start addresses of the applications are as follows:

```
                    Load address    Start address
    x86             0x00040000      0x00040000
    PowerPC         0x00040000      0x00040004
    ARM             0x0c100000      0x0c100000
    MIPS            0x80200000      0x80200000
    Blackfin        0x00001000      0x00001000
    NDS32           0x00300000      0x00300000
    Nios II         0x02000000      0x02000000
```

Answer (score 2):

In arch/arm/config.mk there is:

```
CONFIG_STANDALONE_LOAD_ADDR = 0xc100000
```

In file examples/standalone/.hello_world.cmd

```
cmd_examples/standalone/hello_world := arm-linux-gnueabi-ld.bfd   -g -Ttext 0xc100000 -o examples/standalone/hello_world -e hello_world examples/standalone/hello_world.o examples/standalone/libstubs.o -L /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7 -lgcc
```

Here the -Ttext is 0xc100000. That means hello_world entry address is 0xc100000. So the hello.bin must be loaded to memory address 0xc100000.